# How to sort LinkedHahMap values which is list of custom object

Tags: java

Suppose i've an object like this `LinkedHashMap<String, List<AuditLogs>>`.
Where AuditLog class has property named `modifiedDate`.

I want to sort auditlogs object on the basis of `modifiedDate` irrespective of any key.

Although I've tried but it works me on the basis of keys.Can i have code snippet which work ignoring keys.

Comment: Do you want each separate list corresponding to each individual key sorted? Or do you want a separate list of all `AuditLogs`?

Comment: I want to sort object on the basis of list of AuditLogs or values not on the basis of keys.

Comment: Still not clear what you actually want, check if my answer makes sense.

Comment: so for what did you make the map for?

Comment: It is your `LinkedHashMap<String, List<AuditLogs>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want **all** the audit log values from **all** the keys in one list, sorted by `modifiedDate`:

If your object is `LinkedHashMap<String, List<AuditLogs>> map`:

```
List<AuditLog> sortedAuditLogs = map
   .values()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AuditLog::modifiedDate))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```